# Rewrite Subdomain to query string and mask. Currently looping and 403'ing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

It's been a while!

Hi guys,

So I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
www.domain.com
domain.com -> 301 -> www.domain.com
account-name.domain.com -> mask and ask server for -> domain.com/account/acount-name
account-name.domain.com/page -> mask and ask server for -> domain.com/account/account-name/page
etc..
```

So far I have got this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ account/%1$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

However I keep getting this sort of 403 message, it looks like a loop!

> You don't have permission to access
>   /index.php/account/testindex.php/account/testindex.php/account/testindex.php/account/testindex.php/account/test

Maybe I'm missing something obvious as I've been working on this for a while and gave up last time I tried. Is it even possible?

**My next challenge is...**

Once I get this sorted I am planning on allowing users to setup `CNAMES` and point to our domain.com, I want to be able to rewrite the non domain.com requests to something similar as above in structure if not the same because we can obviously test for the domain format using regex to then load the account from the DB. So ANY suggestions on this would be a bonus :)

**Setup**

Currently using Codeigniter on Apache and Ubuntu 14 Server.

Thanks for any guidance in advanced!

-Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

to

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `L` ensures that this rewrite is the last processing rule for this request. Otherwise Apache will also apply your other rewrite rules as well, leading to this:

> /index.php/account/testindex.php/account/testindex.php/account/testindex.php/account/testindex.php/account/test

Comment: Updated (question now reflects) but still looping :-/

Comment: Ok i saw your updated question, but I think you are doing too much atm. Try to get just one item working at a time and remove all .htaccess declarations not associated with that item. Maybe start with getting only the 302 redirect working first